# Can't launch JD-GUI on Ubuntu 12.04.3 64 bits

Tags: 64-bit, ubuntu-12.04, decompiler

When I launch [JD-GUI](http://jd.benow.ca/) on my Ubuntu 12.04.3 (Precise Pangolin) 64 bits system, nothing happens:

```
user@host:~/jd-gui-0.3.5.linux.i686$ ./jd-gui
user@host:~/jd-gui-0.3.5.linux.i686$
```

How do I launch it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should install package `ia32-libs`.

Comment: On Ubuntu 13.10 x86_64 it should be `sudo apt-get install ib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 libsm-dev:i386 libcanberra-gtk3-module:i386`

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64 it should be sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 libsm6:i386 lib32stdc++6

Comment: he asked how to launch you are answering how to install

Comment: Not really, actually the OP shows a problem on launch, which is a lack of installed lib: jd-gui depends on those ia32 libs and others.

Comment: @ademar111190 Edit :    
 
On Ubuntu 13.10 x86_64 it should be `sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 libsm-dev:i386 libcanberra-gtk3-module:i386`

Answer (score 9):

For Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit, you should use

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine:i386
```

Answer (score 5):

For Ubuntu 14.04, you can use :

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 libsm-dev:i386 libcanberra-gtk3-module:i386
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, all the methods above (apt-get install blabla) don't work.

this worked for me:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:java-decompiler/jd-gui.git
$ gradle build
```

then a file will be generated to : build/libs/jd-gui-1.0.0.jar

run it:

```
$ java -jar build/libs/jd-gui-1.0.0.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another option to use jd-gui on Ubuntu 64 bit. Download jd-gui for Windows and use [Wine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29) to open it. It works fine and without any hassles.

Comment: OP specifically asks for a solution for his linux problem, using windows via wine is like saying take a bike if you want your car fixed

Comment: what they ask is to be able to use it, and they will. your answer is like a very immature one.

Comment: Id like to see you doing this in the real world, little man. but it is so easy to "grow up" in the internet. go ahead. make for the real world here.

Comment: Wine is just an emulator for windows, so this solution works for (almost) _any_ application that should also work on windows. _In my opinion_ this is not what OP was looking for. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252297) if you'd like to see more discussion on downvoting and commenting.